# How to create a Favorites system in ASP.NET Core API with these limitations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, clean-architecture

I want to create a Favorites system in my API but I have some limitations due to architecture.

I'm using Clean Architecture ( or a form of it at least ) in the sense that my project is built as such:

**Project structure**

```
App.Domain
-> App.Application ( has reference to App.Domain )
   -> App.API ( has reference to App.Application )
   -> App.Persistence ( has reference to App.Application )
      -> App.API ( has reference to App.Persistence )
   -> App.Identity ( has reference to App.Application )
      -> App.API ( has reference to App.Identity )
```

( The API being the same one, I only have one API )

Now I'm trying to create a Favorite system this way:

App.Domain -> Entities -> Item.cs

```
public class Item: AuditableEntities
{
    public Item()
    {
    }

    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

App.Identity -> Models -> ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public List<Item> FavoritedItems { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is I can't refer to ApplicationUser from the Item entity because it doesn't know about the Identity project, however I can refer to the Item entity from the ApplicationUser model because it knows about the Domain project.

Should I try to refer to the ApplicationUser model from the Place entity or is there a better way to do it ?

Thank you so much for your help.

---

**EDIT:**

Like @smokesnes advised, I did this:

```
// namespace App.Domain.Entities
public class Item: AuditableEntities
{
    public Item()
    {
    }

public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<IApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}

// namespace App.Domain.Contracts
public interface IApplicationUser
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Gender { get; set; }
    List<Item> FavoritedItems { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an Identity project that has the real `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>, IApplicationUser` like he said.

However now I have a problem, My `AppDbContext` ( App.Persistence ) uses `Configuration` files to know what the relationships are between tables, the `ItemConfiguration` file uses this line to express its one to many relationship with the `IApplicationUser` interface:

**AppDbContext:**

```
// App.Persistence
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ItemConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new FavoriteConfiguration());
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

**ItemConfiguration.cs**

```
// App.Persistence
builder.HasOne<Favorite>(d => d.Favorite)
   .WithMany(d => d.Items);
```

**FavoriteConfiguration.cs**

```
// App.Persistence
builder.HasOne<IApplicationUser>(d => d.User)
            .WithMany(d => d.Favorites);
```

And when I try to run a migration here's what I get:

`System.ArgumentException: The specified type 'App.Domain.Contracts.IApplicationUser' must be a non-interface reference type to be used as an entity type.`

And the problem is I can't change it to `ApplicationUser` because then I have to change it in the `Item` entity and that's where I needed the interface in the first place.

Also, I add a scope to the `ApplicationUser` and its interface in the `App.Identity.IdentityServiceRegistration.cs` that gets added in the `App.Api.Startup.cs.ConfigureServices` method:

**IdentityServiceRegistration.cs**

```
// App.Identity
public static void AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddScoped<IApplicationUser, ApplicationUser>();
    }
```

And for @JeremyLakeman:

**AppIdentityDbContext**

```
// App.Identity
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
{

    public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what should be done ?

Comment: I don't think that work around will work. Since `List<IApplicationUser> != List<ApplicationUser>` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). Maybe you could make it work by introducing a generic constraint `Item<A> where A:IApplicationUser`, but that's going to get messy fast.

Comment: However, do you even need the navigation property? Are you *ever* going to define a query from an Item, joining to the users who have favourited that item? Aren't you more likely to only start you query from the current user? Does an Item care about users at all?

Comment: I want to use the navigation property to understand how it works, you’re absolutely right I don’t need it, however I would like to know why it’s not working and what is the solution

Comment: You could split the definition of `Item` across two projects. Using generic parameters where necessary, which your application then brings together. Similar to how your `AppIdentityDbContext` extends the generic context provided by the Identity framework in order to define `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: So you mean define Item in App.Domain and in App.Persistence.Configurations extend item in the configuration constructor like so: SIGNATURE: ItemConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Item>, Item     CONSTRUCTOR:  public ItemConfiguration( // something ) : base(// something) ?

Comment: Right, extend `Item` in your App.Identity package; `FavouriteItem : Item { public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; } }` then define `DbSet<FavouriteItem>` in your app context. And use generic parameters for `Item` in any service, so you can supply / return a `FavouriteItem` / `IQueryable<FavouriteItem>` instead.

Comment: Ok, so I'm not going to lie I'm a little lost, you seem to understand this a lot better than I do ( my first time connecting Domain entities to Identity objects ), can you please write an answer so that I can understand it better please ? I would love to understand it like you do and mark it as the answer if it works, and also thank you for taking the time

Answer (score 1):

There might be several ways to do this. One simple way is to simply add an interface that the Domain knows about, but the implementation is in another project. As such;

```
// namespace App.Domain.Entities
public class Item: AuditableEntities
{
    public Item()
    {
    }

    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}

// namespace App.Domain.Entities or App.Domain
public interface IApplicationUser
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Gender { get; set; }
    List<Item> FavoritedItems { get; set; }
}
```

And then let your `ApplicationUser` implement this interface:

```
// namespace App.Identity.Models
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IApplicationUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public List<Item> FavoritedItems { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `Item`-entity can deal with the interface without having a tight coupling to the implementation. However, you cannot create the `ApplicationUser` in the `Domain`-project. It will need to be created outside. Or again, you can create a factory where the interface is known to the `Domain`, but the implementation is not.

Comment: Thank you ! I'm going to try this and mark it as the answer if it works !

Comment: @SachaPerson Good luck, and let me know if it doesn't so that we can find another approach.

Comment: Alright so I'm trying it right now, I have a problem when it comes to using IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>, I'm referencing IApplicationUser with builder.HasOne<IApplicationUser>(d => d.Something)
                .WithMany(d => d.SomethingElse); and when I try to run a migration it fails and here's what happens : System.ArgumentException: The specified type 'App.Domain.Contracts.IApplicationUser' must be a non-interface reference type to be used as an entity type. Do you know what should be done ? I've updated my question to make it easier to read and I've added details

Comment: Does it work if you define the foreign key from the other side?

Comment: Do you mean I should try to not define it in FavoriteConfiguration but just on the ItemConfiguration and run the migration to see if it works ?

Comment: Also, I have updated my question again to give more details

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are already using a `DbContext` that extends `IdentityDbContext<...>` in order to define your `ApplicationUser`. So lets borrow a little from this design pattern used by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`, and split your model definition between packages.

You'll probably also need to merge your `AppDbContext` into your `AppIdentityDbContext` so that you only define one context. Otherwise you'll have trouble querying with joins across your models. However, since your context must extend `IdentityDbContext`, this can't be an abstract type.

Your App.Domain package doesn't know anything about `ApplicationUser`, so it can't define any navigations.

```cs
namespace App.Domain
{
    public interface IAppContext<TItem> where TItem : Item
    {
        DbSet<TItem> Items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item: AuditableEntities
    {
        public Item()
        {
        }

        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your App.Identity package does know about users, so it can extend that definition. And define the `DbContext` that your application will actually use.

```cs
namespace App.Identity
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public List<FavouriteItem> FavoritedItems { get; set; }
    }
    public class FavouriteItem : Item
    {
        public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    }
    public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
    {
        ...
        public DbSet<FavouriteItem> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright thank you so much, so I'm going to have to read this a couple times to make sure I understand before I ask questions, however i have one right now, Can the IdentityDbContext be the only DbContext of the whole project even though I have an identity project and a persistence project ? I learned about the fact that I needed two because of the fact that everything was separated into different projects, but I believe that IdentityDbContext inherits from DbContext so I'm sure you're right but how can I make this work for the persistence project then ?

Comment: The persistence project will want the application to define a context with some `DbSet` properties. So you could inject dependencies with something like `class Service<TItem,TContext> where TContext:DbContext, IAppContext<TItem>`. Though that does get a bit messy.

Comment: Or just define the context twice in your `IServiceCollection`; `services.AddScoped<IAppContext<FavouriteItem>>(p => p.GetService<AppIdentityDbContext>());`

Comment: Tell me if I understood it, IAppContext<T> here would be what my current
App.Persistence.AppDbContext is, but now it is an abstraction in order to give full power to the App.Identity.IdentityDbContext and have what's needed for the App.Persistence DbSets to communicate with the IdentityDbContext which they couldn't before right ? 
Also I have questions but I think it'll go faster for you to answer this way, could you please write the namespace over each class in your examples to make sure I understand where everything should be ? Most of my questions are about this at the moment

Comment: RIght, your persistence layer requires some interface to access your `DbSet` and `SaveChanges` methods etc. But it's your application layer that provides the implementation via `IdentityDbContext`. Imagine for a moment, that for dependency management, you go all-in and define interfaces for *everything*. Then you could move all those interfaces to a separate package. Defining all the contracts, but none of the implementations. Each implementation only depends on this interface package. Your startup code brings it all together. You don't have to go that far, but you could.

Comment: So I've tried to do what you've said but it's too hard for me, instead I thought of something else tell me what you think about it, do you think I should have the whole `App.Identity` project absorbed by the `App.Persistence` project since they have the same project references and have only one DbContext there inheriting `IdentityDbContext` ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing Domains here. What you want is probably to split your Domain Models based on their Bounded Contexts, so that each Model class operates only on the data it actually needs.

This would basically mean to have at least one service for User Profiles, handling your `ApplicationUser` models.
Then you'll have a different service for Favorites.